# How to write organic chemical equation of the following form

Tags: chemfig, chemstyle, chemformula

[image]

I need to write this transesterification reaction and give it an equation number. How can I do so?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange.  Have you taken a look at the `chemfig` package with a documentation available at [http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf) ?  It would be great if you could edit your question to give a starting example that shows how far you have progressed.  That would make the task of contributors easier, and you would get your problem solved faster !

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to use two packages for this: [`chemfig`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) and [`chemmacros`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros). `chemfig` handles the drawing part, and `chemmacros` handles scheme numbering and creation of the list of schemes (plus, you need it anyway if you type chemistry with LaTeX).

[image: Reaction scheme]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
    \setchemfig{
        atom sep        = 2em,
        bond join       = true,
    }
\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{
        modules = {all},
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{scheme}
    \centering
    \schemestart
        \chemname{
            \chemfig{
                CH
                (-[:90]CH_2-OOC-R_1)
                (-[:-90]CH_2-OOC-R_3)
                -OOC-R_2
            }
        }{Triglyceride}
        \+
        \chemname{
                \chemfig{
                    3 ROH
                }
            }{Alcohol}
        \arrow(.mid east--.mid west){<=>[Catalyst]}
        \chemname{
            \chemfig{
                R_2
                (-[:90,,,,draw=none]R_1-COO-R)
                (-[:-90,,,,draw=none]R_3-COO-R)
                -COO-R
            }
        }{Alkyl esters}
        \+
        \chemname{
            \chemfig{
                CH
                (-[:90]CH_2-OH)
                (-[:-90]CH_2-OH)
                -OH
            }
        }{Glycerol}
    \schemestop
    \caption{Transesterification of triglyceride with alcohol.}
    \label{scm:tsester}
\end{scheme}

\listofschemes

\end{document}
```